# C++ Pthreads. Arguments to pthread_create

Tags: c++, pthreads, function-pointers, void-pointers

There are a couple of things that I don't understand about the function `pthread_create`.

here is the header

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict thread,
                   const pthread_attr_t *restrict attr,
                   void *(*start_routine)(void*), 
                   void *restrict arg);
```

Firstly, I'm not familiar with the syntax of `void *(*start_routine)(void*),`. I know that the argument asked for here is the name of a function that returns `void *`, and takes one `void *` as its argument. Presumably `pthread_create` will refer to that funcion as `start_routine`. So I suppose this argument would be a function pointer? If so, what are the key syntax elements that make it so?

Secondly, why does `pthread_create` expect a function that has `void *` as its return type? What would `pthread_create` be able to do with data of unkown type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `void *(*start_routine)(void*)` should be read in the following order:

- `start_routine` - Name of the argument.
- `*start_routine` - So this argument is a pointer.
- `(*start_routine)(...)` - Aha, it's a pointer to a function.
- `(*start_routine)(void*)` - We now know the argument(s) of the function.
- `void *(*start_routine)(void*)` - And finally, this tells us the return type of the function.

The `void*` argument receives whatever is passed to `arg` - so if you need to pass any "input" to your new thread this is one way to do it.

The resulting `void*` is used as thread's exit status (as alternative to calling `pthread_exit()` explicitly). You can get this status through `pthread_join()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `void *(*start_routine)(void*)` is a function pointer. Everything about it is the 'key syntax', but in particular the syntax `(*ptrname)(args)`.
2. pthreads doesn't do anything with the void* that the start routine returns except to return it to you. See the man page for `pthread_join` to see how it comes back to you.